# Blazor Wasm: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer restored in server project but not in client project

Tags: authentication, jwt, blazor-webassembly

There is an authentication package for blazor wasm `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` that while downloading in blazor web assembly client project but isn't restored, In server project there is no problem.

I cleared nuget cache, deleted object and bin folders then rebuild. but in nuget manager, there is a cloud with a red icon next to this package in the client project.

Is there any restriction for blazor webassembly types, should not use this package? So how to resolve this issue?

**EDIT**:

As soon as I add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` all client project's packages show yellow exclamation marks. And when I remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` package all other packages are successfuly restored.

This happens in Blazor webassembly client project and the server project has no problem with this package.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, Under the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` in the package manager is written this is a middleware, So it can't be installed on the client project.

I solved my problem by adding: `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` package to client project. This is a sub package of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` that is available separately in nuget.